# Threading and returning a value

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using C# and Visual Studio 2010.  Is this ok or do i need to change it?

```
public bool SomeFunction(string arg1)
{
    bool ok = false;
    var firstThread = new Thread(delegate()
                                     {
                                         ok = SomeFunction2(arg1);
                                     });

    firstThread.Start();
    firstThread.Join();

    return ok;
}
```

Comment: impossible to answer without knowing what SomeFunction2 is doing (ie, spawning another thread)

Comment: why would you spawn another thread and then wait for it to complete? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how long running the process on the other thread is -- but starting the thread and then joining to it confuses me because the join call causes the calling thread to be blocked until the other is finished.

However, if you actually needed the process to run on another thread look up the BackgroundWorker because it will make multi-threading very easy.  You attach to events to manage the background thread, progress reporting, cancellation and completed.

Let me know if you need some help but here is a great example of using a background worker.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: There is only one thread. Some function2 will perform its task and then will pass back true/false which i need to pass back to the caller. So from your explanation, i can take out thread.join?

Comment: Thanks for the info, after looking at your link now i have an idea what i am suppose to do.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to wait for the thread to complete (setting the captured variable `ok` to a new value) before returning `ok`, then it looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 0):

Your exact code doesn't make much sense. But if you have some reason to run the code on another thread, then this should be fine. Although it might be better to use a `Task` that returns the value.